# How to submit independent watchOS6 app to App Stroe Connect?

Tags: ios, upload, watchos

I recently made my first independent watchOS app(built on watchOS6). I have already have my iOS app on sale, and this watchOS app is used to realize a small function of iOS app.

My question is how to upload this watchOS app to App Stroe Connect? I want this watchOS app having the same name as iOS app's, need I creat a new iOS App on App Stroe Connect for this watchOS app?

Comment: Are you trying to add a watchOS app into your current iOS app or are you trying to have it sold separately? Unless you combine the two apps you will need different names.

Comment: @JakeDerouin My watchOS app is built independently, it can run independently without iOS app. I want the watchOS app and my current iOS app share the same App name on App Store. But when I add a new iOS app for uploading the watchOS app on App Store Connect, I enter the same App name, but it says that the App name is already used for other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the watchOS app to share the same name with your iOS app you will have to create a new version of your iOS app as both apps will need to be uploaded together. When you are in Xcode, you will have to upload the watch binary with your iOS app. Since your app can run independently, you can change settings within the project (blue icon on files screen) to allow your app to run independent if the user chooses. This will show as one app in AppStore connect but will allow the user to use your watch app without the iOS app.

Comment: Thanks Jake. What should I do first? Now my iOS app and watchOS app are two different projects with different bundle ids, do you mean I should add a new watchOS target(Watch App) in my current iOS App project?

Comment: Thanks Jake. I got it. I add a watchOS target(Watch App for iOS App) for my current iOS project, add the watch binary will be included in the iOS binary as they can be uploaded to the App Store Connect together. Thank u very much.